# creating a banana object

Tags: javascript, oop

I recently came across a object oriented programming question, and I couldnt figure it out. here are the instructions:

```
1. create a banana object
2. all bananas are yellow
3. all bananas have a length and diameter which are set at instatiation
4. bananas also have isYummy property, which is set to true, because all bananas are yummy.
5. all bananas have the ability to rot, which toggles isYummy to false.
```

I'm really unfamiliar with what it means to instantiate length and diameter, and also functions.

here is my approach.

```
    const Banana = (color, length, diameter, isYummy) => {
        this.color = 'yellow';
        this.length = length;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.isYummy = true
    }

    let rot = new Banana('yellow', length, diameter, false)
```

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const Banana = (color, length, diameter, isYummy) => {
>         this.color = 'yellow';
>         this.length = length;
>         this.diameter = diameter;
>         this.isYummy = true
>     }
>
>     let rot = new Banana('yellow', length, diameter, false)
> ```

All bananas are yellow, so you don't need the color in your arguments, also isYummy is initially set to true, so you don't need that either. the only input you have are length and diameter. (it's long since I code JS, I don't recall the syntax well)

```
const Banana = (length, diameter) => {
        this.color = 'yellow';
        this.length = length;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.isYummy = true
    }

    let myBanana = new Banana(length, diameter)
```

also banana can rot, which is an action, and action are naturally methods. in js instance method are prototype of the object.

in online compiler i had issue with your code so i rewrite it like this:

Banana can be object if it written using function in that compiler.

```
const Banana = function (length, diameter) {
        this.color = 'yellow';
        this.length = length;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.isYummy = true
    };
```

then you need to add an action to it (**Note** if you use => arrow function, the `this` context will be different, and not of the object. so be careful)

```
Banana.prototype.rot = function(){this.isYummy = false;}
```

and now create our banana from the object we just defined.

```
let myBanana = new Banana(20, 3);
console.log(myBanana.isYummy);
```

and now let it rot:

```
myBanana.rot();
console.log(myBanana.isYummy);
```

```js
const Banana = function (length, diameter) {
            this.color = 'yellow';
            this.length = length;
            this.diameter = diameter;
            this.isYummy = true
        };
    
Banana.prototype.rot = function(){this.isYummy = false;}

let myBanana = new Banana(20, 3);

console.log(myBanana.isYummy);

myBanana.rot();

console.log(myBanana.isYummy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with default values in constructor as below:

```
class Banana{
  constructor(length, diameter){    
    this.color = 'Yellow';
    this.length = length;
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.isYummy = true; 
  }
}

var myBanana = new Banana('10cm', '2cm');
// to toggle rot or isYummy property
myBanana.isYummy = false;
console.log(myBanana) // to see your object in console
```

Comment: `color` and `isYummy` shouldn't be configurable from the constructor, as these values are fixed (`color` always, `isYummy` at time of instantiation).

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what you need help with, but here are a few issues I noticed:

- To my knowledge, arrow functions can't be constructors. Trying to instantiate that `Banana` won't work.
- `this.color` and `this.isYummy` are *always* set to true at the beginning, so you don't need to pass the corresponding arguments into the constructor.
- I'm guessing you misunderstood the `rot` thing—it's probably not meant to be a separate variable or property, but simply some piece of logic such as a timeout which will set the `isYummy` property to false:

```
setTimeout(() => { this.isYummy = false }, 1000); // rot after one second
```

Put that at the end of your constructor.

Comment: More likely the requirement is to add a `rot()` method that sets `isYummy` to `false`, to show that classes/objects can have member methods.